# Why doesn't my map work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, dojo, gis

I have developed a WebApp that functions in Chrome, FireFox, and newer IE. Most of the functionality is not working in IE8.

A user inputs a Zip Code and the map zooms to the Zip Code, displays the associated delivery routes, and fills a table with required data from the route.

In IE8, the map doesn't zoom to the extent of the route, nor does the table get filled. 
Here is my code that should zoom to the features of the zip code:

function displayResults(results, messages) {
    var featureset = results[0].value;

```
var simplePolySymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol();
simplePolySymbol.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0, 96, 170, .75]), 1));

dojo.forEach(featureset.features, function (feature) {
    feature.setSymbol(simplePolySymbol);

    resultsLayer.add(feature);
});

myMap.addLayer(resultsLayer);
myMap.Search.handleStats(results, messages);

var extent = esri.graphicsExtent(featureset.features);
myMap.setExtent(extent, true);
}
```

And here is my code which is supposed to populate a table with the route data:

```
myMap.Search = {
gpGetStats: new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor(gpURL),
getRouteStats: function () {
    console.log(dojo.byId('resultsLayer').value);
    var params = {
        "ZIP_CRID": dojo.byId('resultsLayer').value
    };
    resultsLayer.Search.gpGetStats.execute(params, resultsLayer.Search.handleStats);
},

handleStats: function (results, messages) {
    console.log(results);

    var content = '';

    content += '<table>';
    content += '<tr><td> ZIP CRID </td><td> Bus </td><td> Res </td><td> Tot </td><td> &lt;200 </td><td> DS Key </td></tr>';

    dojo.forEach(results[0].value.features, function (crid, i) {
        console.log(crid.attributes.ZIP_CRID + ', ');
        content += '<tr><td>' + crid.attributes.ZIP_CRID;
        content += '</td><td> ' + crid.attributes.BUS_CNT;
        content += '</td><td> ' + crid.attributes.RES_CNT;
        content += '</td><td> ' + crid.attributes.TOT_CNT;
        content += '</td><td> ' + crid.attributes.LT_200_IND;
        content += '</td><td> ' + crid.attributes.DS_KEY + '</td></tr>';
    });
    content += '</table>';
    dojo.byId('details').innerHTML = content;
},
```

Im pretty stuck, can't figure out what to fix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like a code *dump* help other's to help yourself. Just make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3yN3A/ the servers are on a secure network so i dont know if the functionality is going to be there for those not at my place of business

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the dojo library to add the contents to your your html object with the Details ID you can do this yourself with something like:

```
var element=document.getElementById('details');
element.innerHTML = content
```

Check this site for more information and please note that the site shows that this is supported in IE
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS API for Javascript run at IE 8
and dojo run at IE 8

but there is a javascript code not run directly in IE 8

as Chrome and firefox

you must write javascript code correctly to run at IE 8

and IE 8 can`t run this code :

```
dojo.byId('details').innerHTML = content;
```

this link help you to write correct code to run at IE 8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Removing the innerHTML made it so my map zooms in to the associated routes. Now I just need to figure out how to get my table to show.